# Http Post Request - TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable

Tags: http-post, typeerror

I'm trying to write a request for an api to pull a csv for trade histories. I'm having an issue when it gets to the actual request and I'm not sure whether its a client issue, something to do with the libraries, or the way I'm making the request itself. The API is hosted on dYdX's servers and there are a few dependencies -I've follow most of the docs (https://docs.dydx.exchange/).

Here are the imports:

```
from dydx3 import Client
from dydx3 import constants
from dydx3 import epoch_seconds_to_iso
from os import path
import ciso8601
import datetime
import pprint
import subprocess
import sys
import time
import json
```

and here is the client initialization and request:

```
client2 = Client(
        host = _api_host,
        network_id = _network_id,
        api_key_credentials = {
                'key': _api_key,
                'secret': _api_secret,
                'passphrase': _api_passphrase
        }
)
get_account_result2 = client2.private.get_account(
        ethereum_address = _eth_address
)
account2 = get_account_result2['account']
```

It keeps crashing on the line with account2 = get_account_result2['account'], TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable. I've run it through Windows and Linux (Ubuntu) Python 3. I feel like it's a syntax thing with the json? Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the ‘account’ value of that Response object as if it’s a dictionary object (subscriptable) but it is not. The good news is it likely has a method to show you the response in json, text or dictionary from.

To see which methods or attributes the Response object has try:

```
dir(get_account_result2)
```

If there is a "json" method in that list, you might want to try:

```
get_account_result2.json()[‘account’]
```

If there is an "account" attribute (not callable) or method (callable) respectively, you could also try:

```
get_account_result2.account or get_account_result2.account()
```

I dont have a dydx account so I cannot verify if any of this works.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up taking these lines out and it pulled from the API just fine. I also forced the strings as you suggested, worked like a charm. It was pulling a record that was (empty) so forcing it into a string allowed it to just skip right over it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_account_result2.data` to see the account info.

For example:

```
print(get_account_result2.data)
```